# Erro "content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response." -API climatempo

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors

Olá, estou com um problema com o CORS na API do Climatempo, meu código do request é esse:

```
var api_url = '"http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/anl/synoptic/locale/BR?token=TOKEN"';   
$.ajax({
    url: api_url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    }
})
```

Já tentei trocar para `jsonp`, mas também não obtive sucesso, estou travado a bastante tempo aqui e tudo que vi na internet não resolveu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eles não aceitam o `contentType: "application/json",` na configuração do CORs, na verdade nem é necessário, porque o `contentType` não diz o que você espera de resposta, ele só afirma que você esta enviando JSON, mas sua requisição é GET e logo não envia nada, então esse `contentType` nem deveria existir. Mude para:

```
var api_url = '"http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/anl/synoptic/locale/BR?token=TOKEN"';   
$.ajax({
    url: api_url,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    }
})
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ! Agora tenho outro erro Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Você tem que executar em uma página http, como localhost @GabrielNunes em protocolo FILE não funciona.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Deu certo agora!!

Comment: @GabrielNunes por nada, se possivel marque a resposta como correta